# How to Improve UI of Web Application using Shiny

Tags: shiny, shinyjs

I have prepared a Web application on predicting the price using regression, with the help of shiny. 
However I want improve the front end UI aesthetically. 
Foreg. Such as changing font style to Italic in slider input, changing background color of main panel etc. 
Can you please direct me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide a reproducible example and exactly the UI elements you want to change (foreg. aren't detailed enough), I'm going to direct you to [RStudio's Website](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html). This will give you the basic concepts of how to accomplish what you are trying to do.